# SQL Insert Column name as value into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, 1 has columns

```
Year | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May
```

etc.

This needs to be transferred into a table with columns

```
Year | MonthNo | Value
```

I know how the conversion works from the month abbreviation to a number but I have not been able to achieve a kind of for each -> column -> insert into. Please assist.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using unpivot:

```
SELECT Year, MonthNo, Value
FROM 
   (SELECT *
   FROM Table1) p
UNPIVOT
   (Value FOR MonthNo IN 
      (Jan, Feb, Mar)
)AS unpvt;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c55a0/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use [UNPIVOT operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx) in case you are using SQL Server 2005 or later.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Year, MonthNo, Value)
SELECT Year, MonthNo, Value
FROM Table1   
UNPIVOT (Value FOR MonthNo IN (Jan, Feb, Mar)) AS unpvt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT Year,'1', Jan FROM table1
```

This is for january you have to repeat it for all months. Just change the month no. and name.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server you can use unpivot, but for portability I always use a construct like:

```
select Year
,      1 monthno
,      jan_value
from   table
union all
select Year
,      2 monthno
,      feb_value
from   table
...
union all
select Year
,      12 monthno
,      dec_value
from   table
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're doing this within SQL Server, you can do a select statement:

```
SELECT column_name,
       * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'YourTableName'
```

Using that, you could do an insert into statement